# mount webdav fails on reboot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, webdav

i've got a vhost running ubuntu 12.10.
i installed davfs2 and edited my `/etc/fstab` file like the following:

```
https://somedomain.de/webdav.php/somefolder/ /mnt/s02 davfs defaults 0 0
```

now mounting this using `mount -a` works fine. also if i type `reboot` after connecting using ssh on my vhost as root user, my drive gets mounted correctly.

but using the web-backend of my provider (digitalocean) and clicking "reboot" there, i get an error after my machine starts up:

[image: failed boot]

any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error `Could not resolve hostname 'hostname.de': host not found` probably means the network is not up while trying to mount.

It is recommended to set the `_netdev` mount option that means: *device requires network to be available*. This way, it will wait until there is a link available before trying to mount:

```
https://somedomain.de/webdav.php/somefolder/ /mnt/s02 davfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

Comment: ♥ works like a charm. thank you! totally worth the bounty.

Comment: done. thought this happens automatically

Comment: Saved my days. This is a rarely mentioned option for mounting `davfs` while it often needs a network connection to be available.