# Drive in `/etc/fstab`does not mount automatically after reboot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have added the following line to my `/etc/fstab` (with the correct IP...):

```
123.234.123.234:/folder /home nfs defaults 0 1
```

Typing as root `mount -a` mounts the drive, but after reboot I have to mount it manually again. On my other computers, it always works after reboot.

What can the problem be?
PC is under Linux Mint 17 (~ Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/277873/mount-webdav-fails-on-reboot?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The possible culprit is that your network might not be available when the system is processing the fstab.  I believe `auto` is the default but would encourage you to add it.  Also add `delay_connect` to give time for the network to come fully up.

According to the mount manual the `defaults` options are `rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async`.  So you can replace what you have and itemize the defaults while adding the `delay_connect` option.

```
123.234.123.234:/folder /home nfs rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,delay_connect  0 1
```

Comment: Your solution did not work,   however `123.234.123.234:/folder/home nfs _netdev 0 0` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

try the **_netdev** option

*from the man page for mount:*

> The  filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the  system  from  attempting  to  mount  these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).